# CompareValidator date format

Tags: c#, validation, forms

I have an ajax calendar control that I specified the date format to be yyyy-MM-dd.  Is it possible to have the comparevalidator validate that type of date sepcifically and have it fail for everything else?  right now it seems to only take dd-MM-yyyy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I assume validators use the current CultureInfo object  to determine the date format.

```
CultureInfo.DateTimeInfo.ShortDatePattern
```

Try changing the [page culture(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx).

If you don't want to go that route you can always create a custom validator.

Answer (score 1):

Set CultureInvariantValues="true"

from the [docs](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/validation/default.aspx):

> **Culture Invariant Values** -  When doing
>   conversion on a compare validator's
>   non strongly-typed properties
>   (CompareValidator.ValueToCompare,
>   RangeValidator.MaximumValue,
>   RangeValidator.MinimumValue) the
>   validator will use a culture neutral
>   format (Date: YYYY/MM/DD, Double &
>   Currency: US culture format) to do the
>   conversion when CultureInvariantValues
>   is true.

---

**EDIT**

Searching on the web, I found a similar question in another forum, see:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1229615.aspx, maybe the last answer (that was gave by Mohan.Raju) can solve your problem too.

Comment: hahahaah I saw now that I gave the same answer of Sandeep from the asp.net forum.